# How to do OccupancyGrid map compression?

Tags: navigation, mapping, occupancy-grid, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello fellow devs,

I am running move_base on a robot which is connected via WLAN to a laptop running rviz for visualization. The problem is that map updates (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid and nav_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate messages from costmap_2d) saturate the wireless link. Hence, I am looking for a method to compress the map data. Ideally, the solution should be compatible with rviz, but a simple sensor_msgs/Image would also suffice.

Looking around what is available, I found no solution which is working under Hydro/Indigo:

[hector_compressed_map_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_compressed_map_transport) is outdated. It has been written before the  introduction of nav_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate. It can only deal with nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid messages, which are only published once by costmap_2d.

[compressed_visualization_transport](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/?repo=android&r=5abc45517c0915ca8cf378cba7512dc12016888b#hg%2Fcompressed_visualization_transport) is also outdated and doesn't handle OccupancyGridUpdate messages.

To use either of the two, my idea would be to to assemble a complete occupancy grid from the initial OccupancyGrid plus the incemental OccupancyGridUpdate, and feed the result to hector_compressed_map_transport or compressed_visualization_transport. (Pretty much what rviz does on client side, see rviz map_display.cpp line [463](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rviz/html/c++/map__display_8cpp_source.html#l00463))

However, as this is a very hacky solution, I would like to find out if there are any better solutions out there.

Any help is appreciated :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195455/how-to-do-occupancygrid-map-compression?/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-22**:
I think that the bandwidth reduction from the update messages probably reduced the need for continued development of compressed_map_transport.

Is your link that thin? Have you tried reducing the publish rate for map updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We transmit OccupancyGrid messages using the [topic_proxy](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/topic_proxy) which behind the scenes uses [blob_tools](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/blob_tools). During "blobification", data can optionally be compressed using BZ2 (see the text in second link). The compression ratio on real-life grid maps is very high there, reaching from 50:1 up to 100:1.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0